# Best way to access 'local' files to use in Web Audio API when using react?

Tags: reactjs, web-audio-api

I'm working on a way to have low latency '`onClick`' sounds in react. I have a .wav file that I'd like to play with an `audioBufferNode`. However, the only way I'm familiar with processing the .wav into an audio buffer is by using `fetch()` I've tried storing the file in the `/public` directory of my create-react-app initialized project, but that seems to throw error after error.

Is there something I'm missing here? What is the best way to load an audio file, and process it into an audio buffer, when that file is an asset of the react app. Can it be imported and then processed in some way?

Answer (score 2):

Use `fetch()` to grab the files and decode them into an `AudioBuffer` for playback with the Web Audio API.  I recommend using small, compressed files like Opus or MP3 instead of large, raw WAV files. Use [opusenc](https://opus-codec.org/release/dev/2018/09/18/opus-tools-0_2.html) to encode your files. 96kb/s the quality/size sweet spot ([hear comparison](https://opus-bitrates.anthum.com/)).

```js
const audioCtx =  new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)({ latencyHint: 'playback' })
const $ = document.querySelector.bind(document)

initSound(
  'https://batman.dev/static/61881209/50.opus',
  $('#sound1')
)
initSound(
  'https://batman.dev/static/61881209/99.opus',
  $('#sound2')
)

function initSound(url, playbackButton) {
  fetch(url)
  .then(resp => resp.arrayBuffer())
  .then(arrayBuffer => audioCtx.decodeAudioData(arrayBuffer))
  .then(audioBuffer => {
    playbackButton.onclick = () => playSound(audioBuffer)
    playbackButton.disabled = false 
  })    
}

function playSound(audioBuffer) {
  const bufferSource = audioCtx.createBufferSource()
  bufferSource.buffer = audioBuffer;
  bufferSource.connect(audioCtx.destination);
  bufferSource.start(0);  
}
```

```css
html { background: #181e2d; padding: 1rem; }
button { padding: 1em 2em; color: #999; border: none; }
button:enabled { color: #fff; background: #0095ff; cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<button id="sound1" disabled>▶  Snap</button>
<button id="sound2" disabled>▶  Hey!</button>
```